# Android Turbine won't triggers event from liveData that converted to flow by .asFlow()

Tags: android, unit-testing, turbine

[Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) is very handily tool for test flows.
But I have an issue when convert live data to flow like:

```
 fun foo(
    ): Flow<B> =
        bar().asFlow()
            .map { -> }
```

And then in test class:
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val testScope: TestScope = TestScope(testDispatcher)

@Before
fun init() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

@Test
fun testFoo() = testScope.runTest {
    foo().test{
     val result = awaitItem()
     Assert.assertEquals(expected, result)
     awaitComplete()
    }
}
```

Then I got this error

```
After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [ScopeCoroutine{Active}@35c3ef4a]
```

Previously I faced this issue and find out that in some case should awaitComplete() but it some case that will also not works.

Comment: What are you trying to use `awaitComplete` for here? That will wait until the Flow you're testing completes, but in the case of a Flow created by converting a LiveData, that will never happen.

Comment: https://github.com/cashapp/turbine/issues/117